# Function calls messing with each other

Tags: javascript, forms, spring-mvc

I have following code in my popup jsp:

```
<input type="submit" value="Mod" onclick="remind()" ></input> &nbsp;
<input type="hidden" value="Mod" name="db_remind" id ="remindbutton"></input> &nbsp;
<%--
<input type="submit" value="Delete"  onclick="confirmDelete()" > </input>
<input type="hidden" value="Delete"  name="db_delete" id="deletebutton" > </input>
```

Hidden button calls for a Spring controller method. Script is needed to close the popupwindow right after the method is committed.

Each script is like:

```
    function save() {
    $('#savebutton').click();
    window.close();
```

}

My problem is that my solution works only, if only one of the jsp function calls is present, in each case. You might say that my solution to achieve what i want is a bit silly, but im a newbie with this and i wonder why all the function calls cannot work together?

Answer (score 0):

Please edit the question to make your issue more clearer. From what I can see you are trying to call different java script functions on click of different buttons.

Do not use input type = "submit" for the buttons. Use input type = "button"

```
<input type="button" value="remindId" onclick="remind()" ></input>
<input type="button" value="saveId" onclick="save()"></input>
```

And in javascipt tag:

```
<script>
function remind()
  { /* Do form submit here */}

function save()
  { /* Do form submit here */}
</script>
```